# Upgrade to 2019.2.13 causes Namespace name `EventSystems' could not be found

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have upgraded from 2018.3.14f to 2019.2.13 and I started having really strange errors.

I am now having those two errors:

> The type or namespace name `EventSystems' does not exist in the namespace`UnityEngine'. Are you missing an assembly reference?

and

> The type or namespace name `UI' does not exist in the namespace`UnityEngine'. Are you missing an assembly reference?

This is happening only to the project which I upgraded from 2018.3.14 to 2019.2.13.

If I create a new blank project with 2019 there is no issue. The namespaces are found plus when I go to `New2019Project/Library/ScriptAssemblies/` I can see the following files:

[image]

Then If I go to my upgraded old project in this dir `OldUpgradedTo2019Project/Library/ScriptAssemblies/` the folder is having only those files:

[image]

As you can see I don't have those files in my updated project. If I try to copy the ones from the new working one into my old upgraded, at the time I start the Unity for the upgraded old project it deletes them and the problem stays.

Is there any way I can fix this annoying problem?

Comment: does it do it in a new project?

Comment: Have you tried updating to a different 2019 version, or just 2019.2.13 specifically? It might be worth trying to do the update to a new big version (2018 > 2019) in smaller steps. E.g update to 2019.1 first, then to 2019.2

Comment: @BugFinder not it does not do that in new Project.

Comment: then there must be a way to fix it.. at least is the good news.   So, have you tried removing library, obj, and any build folders

Comment: I have tried removing onl Library folder but no success. Which others to remove also ?

Comment: i just said :D which

Comment: Which are other Build folders? Only Library and Obj ?

Comment: well only you know what you called your build folders, there may also be a temp in there too

Answer (score 1):

What fixed this issue for me was to update to the latest 'Visual Studio Code Editor' in the Unity Package Manager. To do this, go to window -> package manager -> set 'All Packages' to 'In Project', select the Visual Studio Code Editor and update.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue, but my problem was that I had multiple `Google.VersionHandler.dll` files in separate folders within Assets. As a result, the `.asmdef` files were not loading. Here's how I fixed it:

1. Close Unity and Visual Studio
2. Remove the extra copy of `Google.VersionHandler.dll`
3. Delete all `.csproj` and `.sln` files
4. Delete `Library`, `obj`, and `Temp` directories
5. Reopen Unity
6. Click `Assets` > `Open C# Project` to regenerate `.csproj` and `.sln` files

Hope this works for you!

Answer (score 0):

I update my Visual Studio 2017 to Visual Studio 2019, then everything works.

Hope this works for you.